# Skip last two rows dynamically while scraping a html table : BS4 Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a html table from a platform. After retrieving all values i want to skip last two rows of the table, each row is a separate table. Can any one help ?

I am following this approach:

```
new_data = [[c.text.rstrip(" km²") for c in i.find_all('td')]  for i in soup.find_all('table')]
```

Sample html:

[image: Table]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to limit your for loop by using range?

```
for i in range(0, len(soup.find_all('table'))-2)
    foo [i]
```

Otherwise, you could move all the data into a temporary list and then remove the last two from that, then loop through your modified temporary list.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the last two tables you can just skip them in your list comprehension:

`new_data = [[c.text.rstrip(" km²") for c in i.find_all('td')]  for i in soup.find_all('table')[:-2]]`

`soup.find_all('table')[:-2]` will find all `table` tags in your `soup` object, minus the final 2.